# shiny binding for textArea - cannot set initial value

Tags: javascript, r, tags, shiny

I am using a textArea in a Shiny app to provide input to dplyr's filter verb. I use a shiny binding so the input is passed to dplyr only after the return key is pressed. This is working nicely except that I cannot set an initial value for the textArea. Unfortunately this is critical in my app because it is the feature I rely on to save and restore state. I can set the initial value for a text input (returnTextAreaInput1) but not for text area (returnTextAreaInput2).

Below the R and js code I am using. If you run the code from the Desktop you will see that text_out1 shows the initial value while text_out2 does not. Unfortunately I need a textarea.

[image]

```
returnTextAreaInput1 <- function(inputId, label, value = "") {
  tagList(tags$label(label, `for` = inputId), br(),
          tags$input(id = inputId, type = "text", value = value,
                     class="returnTextArea form-control"))
}

returnTextAreaInput2 <- function(inputId, label, value = "") {
  tagList(
    tags$label(label, `for` = inputId),br(),
    tags$textarea(id=inputId, type = "text", value = value, rows="3",
                  class="returnTextArea form-control")
  )
}

setwd("~/Desktop")

ui <- basicPage(
    includeScript("returnTextAreaBinding.js"),
    returnTextAreaInput1("ret1", "Select 1:", "init text 1"),
    returnTextAreaInput2("ret2","Select 2:", "init text 2"),
    textOutput("text_out1"),
    textOutput("text_out2")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$text_out1 <- renderPrint({
    input$ret1
  })

  output$text_out2 <- renderPrint({
    input$ret2
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Below is the js-code for the binding.

```
// based on https://gist.github.com/xiaodaigh/7150112
var returnTextAreaBinding = new Shiny.InputBinding();
$.extend(returnTextAreaBinding, {

    find: function(scope) {
        return $(scope).find('.returnTextArea');
    },
    getId: function(el) {
        return $(el).attr('id')
    },
    getValue: function(el) {
        return el.value;
    },
    setValue: function(el, value) {
        el.value = value;
    },
    subscribe: function(el, callback) {
        $(el).on('keyup.textInputBinding input.textInputBinding', function(event) {
            if(event.keyCode == 13) { //if enter key is pressed
                callback()
            }
        });
    },
    unsubscribe: function(el) {
        $(el).off('.textInputBinding');
    },
    receiveMessage: function(el, data) {
        if (data.hasOwnProperty('value'))
            this.setValue(el, data.value);
        if (data.hasOwnProperty('label'))
            $(el).parent().find('label[for=' + el.id + ']').text(data.label);
        $(el).trigger('change');
    },
    getState: function(el) {
        return {
            label: $(el).parent().find('label[for=' + el.id + ']').text(),
            value: el.value
        };
    },
    getRatePolicy: function() {
        return {
            policy: 'debounce',
            delay: 250
        };
    }
});
Shiny.inputBindings.register(returnTextAreaBinding, 'shiny.returnTextArea');
```

Edit: As suggested this function works as expected

```
returnTextAreaInput <- function(inputId, label = "", value = "") {
  tagList(
    tags$label(label, `for` = inputId),br(),
    tags$textarea(id=inputId, type = "text", rows="2",
                  class="returnTextArea form-control", value)
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `value` as the first argument of your `tags$textarea` function, it will be added between the html textarea tags as default:

```
returnTextAreaInput2 <- function(inputId, label, value = "") {
        tagList(
                tags$label(label, `for` = inputId),br(),
                tags$textarea(value,id=inputId, type = "text", value = value, rows="3",
                              class="returnTextArea form-control")
        )
}
```